# Display Xml From an API

Tags: android

Right now I'm in the process of making an app that streams video from the popular streaming site "Own3d.tv". The app is going great and I'm almost ready for release. I have the own3d TV API and basically I want to fetch the top streams and display them in the app. So I would want to acquire the Name of the stream/streamer along with the view count.

The link to the XML page would be something like this: ("http://api.own3d.tv/live.php?game=LoL")

I'm pretty sure this is possible to do. So if someone could help me out or just point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely possible and and is rather easy to achieve, see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).

Comment: Thanks will be looking at this tomorrow. I will defiantly post back if I run into trouble. Thanks for the help/response.